# React Native panresponder elements clickable?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, animated

I have moveable panresponders but I also need to click on one to have an onPress event. Is this possible? Currently they are `<View>` elements but if I change them to `<Touchableopacity>` or something like that it throws an error. It seeems only `<View>` elements can be animated?

Answer (score 4):

check this here

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3082

`onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {
     return gestureState.dx != 0 && gestureState.dy != 0;
},`